# D3 Updating Data Overlays Second Graph Instead of Updating

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph

I'm pretty new to D3 and am working on a reusable bar chart which can be sent new data and it will update the existing graph based on the new data that it receives.

Currently, it is correctly drawing the chart, but when the data changes it is overlaying a graph of the new data over the old graph instead of updating it.

I believe the issue must be with my `bars` variable and how I'm binding my data but I can't be sure. The data is simply the score of a reddit post from the reddit JSON API.

Example:
[image: Graph problem]

My code for the chart is:

```
d3.namespace.barChart = function() {
var data, group, height, margin = {top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0}, width;

function chart(container) {
  group = container;
  // Determine the max score and timestamps from the Reddit data for use in our scales
  var maxScore = d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.data.score; });
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.data.created *= 1000;
  });

  // Create the scales to ensure data fits in the graphs
  var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(d3.range(data.length))
    .rangeBands([0, width], 0.25);

  var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, maxScore])
    .range([0, height]); // .range(starting, )

  var yScaleLine = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, maxScore])
    .range([height, 0]);

  var colorScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.data.score; }))
    .range(['#DA4453', '#A0D468'])
    .interpolate(d3.interpolateRgb);


  // Create the Y-Axis function. yScaleLine is used as the scale to ensure
  // that the data goes from 0 at the bottom left to max score in the top left
  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yScaleLine)
    .orient('left');

  // Setup our chart using our width, height and margins.
  group.attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

  // Add a group element for the primary graphic that is moved
  // using the margins. Left and top are used since 0,0 is top left corner
  var graph = group.append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

  // Append our yAxis to the SVG canvas and move it according to the margins
  group.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'y axis')
    .call(yAxis)
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

  // Inside of our group, we need to make a 'rect' for each item in the dataset
  // We link the data, and append one rect for each piece of data.
  var bars = graph.selectAll('rect')
    .data(data, function(d) { return d.data.id; });

  bars.enter()
    .append('rect');
    // We begin with the height of each bar as 0 allowing us to transition to their full height
  bars.attr({
      x: function(d, i) { return xScale(i); },
      y: function() { return height; },
      height: 0,
      width: xScale.rangeBand(),
      fill:  function(d) { return colorScale(d.data.score); }
    });


    // Events must be linked before a transition to function
    bars.on('mouseover', function() {
      d3.select(this).attr('fill', '#000');
    })
    .on('mouseleave', function() {
      d3.select(this).attr('fill', function(d) { return colorScale(d.data.score); });
    });


    bars.transition().duration(150)
    .attr({
      x: function(d, i) { return xScale(i); },
      y: function(d) { return height - yScale(d.data.score); },
      height: function(d) { return yScale(d.data.score); },
      width: xScale.rangeBand()
    });

  bars.exit().transition().duration(150).attr({ height: 0.0001 }).remove();
}
```

**EDIT:**
After digging into the created source it seems it's not updating but rather just continuing to create a new svg `g` element for all the `rect`s. Removing the `group.append('g')` chain fixes the graph not updating but the graph is no longer in a group and makes the SVG very messy.
[image: Source Code Problem]

Comment: What happens when you change:  bars.exit().transition().duration(150).attr({ height: 0.0001 }).remove(); to bars.exit().remove();

Comment: Same issue. I've updated the post to include what's happening in the source code with it creating multiple g's. Removing the group.append('g') fixes it but then the graph isn't in a group.

Comment: Append the `g` elements only if they don't exist, otherwise select them.

Comment: You only bind the data to your individual bars. If you bind the data to the graph (or container) itself, then you can do what Lars is suggesting

Comment: I love this because I actually want to create an overlay on purpose. thanks!